# Security of using PHP to return JSON data

Tags: php, xcode, json

I have a PHP and MySQL server to retrieve data, currently I use it with Xcode implementation. I currently concern about the security issue about that. I don't have SSL connection.

the way I make it a little security:

- Using POST
- Return by JSON_decode
- and with a unique string like - $_POST['security_code'], if it is not identical then return 0

Will these two method fairly okay or any suggestion about that, since I am worried about a malicious client making http calls to my app (Quoted by ctrahey)

Thanks

Comment: You're going to describe your concerns in more detail: are you worried about a malicious client making http calls to your app, someone snooping on the client/server interactions, someone impersonating your server, something else?

Comment: Sorry for my misleading. Yes, you are correct! I am worried about a malicious client making http calls by IE

Comment: The first two don't provide any security -- and I'm not clear on what you're describing in your third bullet point. Where does the security code come from? How is it validated?

Comment: in my Xcode implementation, i will add an extra variable called "security_code" in my XCode. When POST is execute, "security_code" will be the first IF-ELSE statement procedure. If that "security_code" is not as same as in PHP, it will return NULL or else it will execute into my real data. Hope you can understand my meaning. Thanks